# Removing all templates from SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server-2012, ssms

So in SSMS, the template browser has all of these preloaded templates that i personally will never use.  I'd rather just clear this out so i can start my own structure, however, everytime i delete them from:

C:\Users[user]\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Templates

and reboot SSMS, they all magically reappear.  The templates that are in there are more or less worthless to me, but i would like to get out of saving query projects or quick templates to a folder and just put them in here for organization and ease.  There's no settings that i can find that causes the behavior so i was wondering if anyone had an idea how to disable this feature.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you want to remove the default templates completely, we need to delete the files and folders under both of the following folders:

**64-bit SQL Server:**

```
%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql

C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Templates\Sql\
```

**32-bit SQL Server:**

```
%ProgramFiles%\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\ManagementStudio\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql

C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\SQL Server Management Studio\11.0\Templates\Sql\
```

Comment: indeed, here's an important tip though:  don't delete the SQLFile.sql or you wont be able to hit "new query" :-)  .  I'm so happy not to see all those n00b templates there anymore and my folders are at the top and alphabetized :D

Answer (score 1):

In SSMS 2008 R2 the folders are:
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Binn\VSShell\Common7\IDE\SqlWorkbenchProjectItems\Sql
C:\Users\<user>\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\100\Tools\Shell\Templates\Sql

Instead of deleting the existing templates, I created a "z MS Shipped" folder and moved them into there, just in case.